# AWS DMS Mongodb to S3 Getting in Loop Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-migration, aws-dms, dms

I have an AWS migration task that extracts data from mongodb and send to s3 in csv file.
After running the tasks for some days, I noticed that DMS was running without errors in the interface but the data was not being updated anymore.

Taking a look in the logs I noticed that it's in a loop with the following error:

```
2022-12-09T13:07:28 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]I: Connection string: 'mongodb://user:****@host:27017/?retryWrites=false&authSource=admin&ssl=true' (mongodb_imp.c:398)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]I:  MongoDB version: 4.2.23  (mongodb_imp.c:200)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: MongoDB version: 4.2.23 (mongodb_imp.c:200)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Target components st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ was reattached after 6 seconds.  (subtask.c:1393)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Target components st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ was reattached after 6 seconds. (subtask.c:1393)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TASK_MANAGER    ]I:  Starting component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ  (subtask.c:1399)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Starting component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ (subtask.c:1399)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Failed to open repository of URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI task. [1000153]  (file_imp.c:4916)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Failed to open repository of URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI task. [1000153] (file_imp.c:4916)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Failed to get task repository of the URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI task. [1000153]  (file_utils.c:217)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Failed to get task repository of the URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI task. [1000153] (file_utils.c:217)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00   2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Could not get table definition for table: my_table_name. [1000100] (file_apply.c:527)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Failed to create file writers for on directory: /rdsdbdata/data/tasks/URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI/bucketFolder [1000100]  (file_apply.c:569)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Failed to create file writers for on directory: /rdsdbdata/data/tasks/URVPYB3AR42L2WPI3ARERUDPO1W43LQASV3PBXI/bucketFolder [1000100] (file_apply.c:569)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Could not init data file writers. [1000100]  (file_apply.c:608)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Could not init data file writers. [1000100] (file_apply.c:608)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Error executing command [1000100]  (streamcomponent.c:1980)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Error executing command [1000100] (streamcomponent.c:1980)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TASK_MANAGER    ]I:  Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ [1000100]  (subtask.c:1414)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ [1000100] (subtask.c:1414)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00

2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Target component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ was detached because of recoverable error. Will try to reattach  (subtask.c:1537)
2022-12-09T12:46:58 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Target component st_0_PHZ527O26SQUKBXSWUIR4AOPAAAO4TPUIBEEMUQ was detached because of recoverable error. Will try to reattach (subtask.c:1537)

2022-12-09T09:46:58.000-03:00   2022-12-09T12:46:58 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Destroying mongoc client: '2103315958236' (mongodb_imp.c:1161)
```

I haven't found nothing about this error yet. If someone have any ideia, that would help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find out the reason / fix for this ?